# Can one delete a Gmail attachment but keep the email?

Tags: gmail, gmail-attachments

My Gmail account is starting to get full, so I have been using the new search term `larger:1M` to find messages containing attachments that are larger than 1 Megabyte.

How do I delete only the attachment without deleting the email itself?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes.

You can access your Gmail account as an IMAP account using an email client such as Thunderbird or MS Outlook and then use the client’s feature for deleting attachments.

Also you can automatically forward the messages to yourself and remove the attachment with Google's Docs. See [Delete only Attachments in Gmail without Deleting the Emails using Google Docs](https://techawakening.org/delete-attachments-from-gmail-without-deleting-the-emails/1842/)

Comment: @jjs: I've noticed that Apple Mail doesn't work properly anymore. It removes the attachment from the email but then leaves behind a *copy* of the original email (which is only visible in the Gmail webapp). This leads to a cumbersome workflow: remove attachment in Apple Mail, then look for the same email in the Gmail webapp, click on the copy with the attachment, then click the "..." menu and select "Delete". Is there a better way to do this with Apple Mail?

Answer (score 57):

I created [Unattach](https://unattach.app/), a web app that lets you mass delete Gmail attachments without deleting the email. You can also download attachments, resize image attachments or upload attachments to your own server or Dropbox.

Comment: Just tried on 4 emails and it worked beautifully. Thank you for making such an app!

Comment: Confirmed, works flawless. Adds a few lines of details to the mail about the attachments that are removed

Comment: Terrific work, Rok.  Flawless OAuth, search/filter, downloading, and breadcrumb insertion -- all without mucking any of my Gmail labels.

Comment: Big fan of Unattach! Freed up a couple hundred MB of Google storage :)

Comment: "Adds a few lines of details to the mail about the attachments that are removed"
"breadcrumb insertion"

Interestingly... I don't see anything added. I tried both `Delete attachments` and `Download and delete attachments` and the only difference was in the labels that got added, but there was no trace of the attachment that was removed. I don't see any setting either. I built the app from source, so can't be missing any features. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @haridsv, it should work like shown in https://youtu.be/2HRn2mVBtgQ even when built from source. If it doesn't, please report a bug on GitHub (https://github.com/rokstrnisa/unattach), and I'll look into it as soon as I can. Thanks!

Comment: @RokStrniša Excellent video, brief but still detailed enough! Looking at the sample at the end, I now understand how the breadcrumb information should look like and I can confirm again that it is missing in the two emails that I processed. I don't have the original email as I had the default settings, but I changed it such that the original is moved to trash instead of permanently getting deleted. I can try again with another email and file a bug, but is there a debug log that I can generate for you to better understand the problem?

Comment: @haridsv Thanks! You can find the log through the menu "Help > Open log file". Let's continue this offline: you can use the menu "Help > Give feedback".

Comment: Found the issue and sent a fix: https://github.com/rokstrnisa/unattach/pull/24

Comment: @haridsv Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just bought this app, and I find it well designed and quite effective at doing what it's for. The developer is also very responsive on Github.

Comment: I just bought the app and removed a few hundred attachments and cleared a ton of space, all without blasting the long and possibly useful conversations.

Comment: The "reduce image size" option is even better than deleting it. =)
PS: I'd add "images old than X" to the base options, but can already be done using advanced query as `olden_than:6m`.

Comment: This looks like the right solution. Great little single-purpose app built by a top-tier engineer as a side project.

Answer (score 36):

*(2022 Update in the edit below)*

A Chrome extension was said to do this, but it was unclear for me (I didn't find the answer on their website) if our emails' content and attachments - i.e. our personal data - transit via this 3rd party company's servers *or not* when using it. As it could be potentially dangerous to open our data to a 3rd party company, I never used it.

As mentioned in @IgorIschuk's answer, it **is possible** to remove attachments in emails (and keep the original text) by enabling IMAP in Gmail + Thunderbird, but the workflow is quite long.

Thus, here is a detailed workflow explaining **how to mass remove attachments for, say, all the emails of your Gmail that have a size > 1 MB**. In my case I had ~ 1050 such emails.

1. First enable IMAP in Gmail's Settings. Also create a Gmail label named `bigattachments`, and configure it to be visible from IMAP.
2. Install Thunderbird (tested with Thunderbird Setup 60.5.0.exe) and set up the Gmail account.
3. In Thunderbird, go in `All mail`, right click on the columns, and enable the display of the column `Size`. Click on the `Size` column header to sort all your emails by size. Then select all the emails that have a size > 1 MB, and move them (with a drag'n'drop) to the `bigattachments` folder.
4. Now create a **local** folder in ThunderBird named `temp`. Drag'n'drop to copy all the emails from `bigattachments` (IMAP, on distant server) to `temp` (local). This step can take a long time depending on the size of the data to be downloaded.
5. Then install the addon [AttachmentExtractor Continued](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor-continued/) (the original addon AttachmentExtract doesn't work on Thunderbird 60 anymore).
6. Now select all the emails in the local `Temp` folder. Right click, select *"Extract attachments"*, select a destination path for the attachments. Wait. Carefully check that the attachments are removed from the emails (you can check the `Size` column), and that they are saved in the destination path too.
7. Now go to Gmail's web (https://mail.google.com/mail), go to Settings, temporarily switch to `Conversation mode off`, `Save settings`. Go to the `bigattachments` label. Check that the number of emails here is equal to the number of emails you processed in Thunderbird. (Note: if you don't switch to `Conversation mode off`, you won't be able to see the right count of emails, you would get a count of conversations instead!).
   Now **delete all these emails** in the `bigattachments` label. This is scary the first time, but it works. Wait a few minutes, refresh Gmail web, and enjoy the change from *5 GB of 15 GB used* to *1GB used* :)
8. Go back to Thunderbird. Select all the emails in the local `Temp` folder. Drag'n'drop them back to the `bigattachments` label (IMAP). Wait for the upload.
9. It's done! You can check on Gmail web that the `bigattachments` contain the same emails, but with attachments removed. You can now do the cleanup: a) Remove this `bigattachments` label (removing a label doesn't delete its emails), b) Go back to `Conversation view on`, c) Delete the Thunderbird's `Temp` local folder, or even remove Thunderbird.

Notes:

- For me *AttachmentExtractor Continued* worked for normal attachments, but not for "inline images" (even if I checked [Also extract embedded 'inline' images too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfBGj.png)), maybe this feature is not working yet. I you have a solution for this, please drop a comment.
- Why copy the emails to a local folder `Temp`, extract the attachments there, delete the original emails in Gmail, and move the content from `Temp` back to Gmail? This seems unnecessarily complicated, and we could think *"Let's apply AttachmentExtractor Continued directly to the `bigattachments` IMAP folder"*! Short answer: the latter doesn't work, already tested!  This is due to [a Thunderbird bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=679619).
- If you only have a few emails to process (less than 10), it's not necessary to install the addon `AttachmentExtractor Continued`. You can skip step 5 and 6, and just click on every email of the `Temp` folder, and click on the bottom right part of the screen (I don't remember the name of this option, maybe it's in `More...`), you have a `Detach` feature. The only drawback is that this cannot be done for multiple emails at the same time.
- Don't forget to do enable *"Delete the attachment from the message"* in the *Tools > Addon options > AttachmentExtractor* menu. If not, the attachments won't be removed from the emails! I don't know which of the 3 options is the best (normal Thunderbird code vs. Delete with AE's internal routine vs. Detach with AE's internal routine; BTW does anyone know what is the difference between the 2 last ones: *Delete* vs. *Detach*?), though.

  [image]

---

***Update 2022-07-29***

1. It only works with **specific** older versions of Mozilla Thunderbird and AttachExtractor (add-on for the former). Thunderbird 68.9.0 downloads can be found [here](https://releases.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/68.9.0/). AttachmentExtractor 2.0.12 can be found [here](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor-continued/versions/).
2. Enable IMAP in Gmail's settings.
3. Create a new label called something like "attachments_for_deletion". If this is an infrequent admin task you can delete this label when finished.
4. Install Thunderbird. When asked if you want to configure with a particular email, do so. Follow all the stuff about passwords and authenticating (I needed my phone to confirm to Google).
5. **VERY IMPORTANT!** You absolutely have immediately to prevent TBird from updating automatically. The little devil will start trying to do that the minute you start it, so here are precise instructions: click hamburger icon (top right) --> Options --> Options --> Advanced (icon at bottom) --> tab "Update". Check "Check for updates but let me..." and **uncheck** "Use a background service...". It will *still* ask to update at least once, but ignore (obviously).
6. Add the "AttachmentExtractor" add-on in TBird: Hamburger icon (top right) --> Add-ons --> Add-ons. Gearwheel icon --> Install Add-ons from File. Find the file downloaded in step 1.
7. "Restart" when TBird asks whether you want to.
8. Select (in TBird) the emails you want to process in the "folder" "Inbox" (or any other "folder" - each represents a label in your account) under your account. If you want to see the (data) size of emails, for example, click on the little icon at the far right (right of column "Date") in Tbird and check "Size". Then you can, for example, order by size, by clicking the relevant column. Then select.
9. Create a **local** folder in the Thunderbird app (right-click "Local Folders") named "temp".
10. Drag'n'drop (in TBird) to copy the emails you have selected from "attachments_for_deletion" (this folder icon is on the distant server) to temp (local folder). This step can take a long time depending on the size of the data to be downloaded. There is no indication that things are happening. Try with a few emails initially until you have confidence it works!
11. Select (in TBird) all the emails in the local temp directory.
12. Right-click and choose "AE Extract from messages" --> "Just Delete attachments...". Confirm (click OK when it says "are you sure?")
13. Select all these emails in temp, and Drag'n'drop back to the "attachments_for_deletion" folder. This should take minimal time because your attachments have now gone!
14. Select emails in "attachments_for_deletion" and return them (Drag'n'drop) to the account's folders as appropriate. What you are actually doing by this process is, for each message concerned, removing the tag "attachments_for_deletion" and adding the tag of the "subfolder" concerned.
15. Done! Now look at your emails in your Gmail web client. Initial disappointment: the attachments still seem to be there. But look closer: they now say "Deleted: My_file_which_used_to_exist.doc". If you click on the icon of the attachment, Google will respond with a confused message: "Couldn't preview file ... "

Comment: This sounds cool, I have to try it! The way TB natively detaches attachments is quite cool. It leaves behind an <1KB file with the same name (text file). So when you go back to Gmail you can see that there was an attachment and what it was called.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a trillion!

Comment: @DanZ Haha, glad it was helpful! Did you succeed with all the steps? It's quite a long process, I do it once every 2 years and I plan a few hours for that ;)

Comment: Yep, it was quite simple to follow. I first ran a sanity check on a few messages, then did the whole job. I did have a slight problem with step #8 - out of ~1800 messages, Thunderbird uploaded ~1000, then stopped silently, and I couldn't get it to updload the rest without restarting the program.  Also, Thunderbird was quite sluggish during the process, because I had had just installed it and it was busy syncing the Inbox and all other folders. Maybe it would have been better to wait (quite a while) until the syncing was done, before running your procedure.

Comment: I'm surprised this answer doesn't have more upvotes. The Thunderbird bug described in the comments to the 1st answer seems to be the standard behavior of all IMAP clients (I also tried Outlook and IMAPSize, they also just create an additional copy of the email, leaving the original with the attachment in place). I was about to give up and pay Google for more space, when I found your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, AttachmentExtractor Continued says: "From version 78, Thunderbird only supports the necessary interfaces for this add-on via "WebExtension Experiments". A lot of program code of the add-on would have to be rewritten for this. It is not expected that the necessary interfaces will be permanently implemented in Thunderbird (as MailExtension API), and the "WebExtension Experiments" will also be removed in the future, which is why the effort is no longer worthwhile. Therefore, this add-on will no longer receive an update and it will not be available for Thunderbird 78."

Comment: @iJames For this reason, you can easily keep a "portable installation" of Thunderbird 77 somewhere that you only use once a year to perform this action. That's what I do, see https://superuser.com/questions/1561967/how-to-run-thunderbird-in-a-portable-way-without-using-c-users-user-appdata-ro.

Comment: @Firsh-LetsWP.io "The way TB natively detaches attachments is quite cool. It leaves behind an <1KB file with the same name (text file)." -- is this also applicable for detachment done via the `AttachmentExtractor Continued` addon?

Comment: @Basj I don't see releases between 68 and 78 being available for download: https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/releases/. Looks like none of them went past a beta stage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Mozilla_Thunderbird. I guess 68 is what we should use then?

Comment: @haridsv In fact, I only use Thunderbird once a year to do this process. So even a good old Thunderbird 60 does the job perfectly.

Comment: @haridsv Yup. https://letswp.io/remove-attachments-gmail-free-space/

Comment: @Basj please could you add step 5 to step 2 since they both need to be confirmed working before emails are downloaded, and also it need to be v77 apparently: https://releases.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/77.0b1/

Comment: Also: as soon as you install v77 and setup your account, IMMEDIATELY goto preferences and uncheck "automatically upgrade". Also2: if you set this up, downloaded all messages (12gb in my case), and then it upgraded, you can't unpack v77 to a new directory and point to the already-downloaded profile folder, as the versions are incompatible. BOO.

Comment: Edit: looks like it should be release 68 max, so https://releases.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/68.9.0/ works with the extension. To disable updates: preferences, wizard hat, update tab.

Comment: This is the answer... in fact it's not really all that complicated. However, things have changed significantly since you posted it in 2019 so I am going to suggest an update to take account of everything new (and all the comments about old versions of TBird and AttachmentExtractor). Unfortunately I can't add an answer because I don't have any rep in this particular SE forum, grrr.

Comment: @mikerodent Please post an answer (I think you can post an answer with 101 rep!) it would be useful.

Comment: No! Mad stuff but it won't let me answer because this is a "highly active question": I have to have at least 10 points! I'm currently adding an edit to your answer. The other solution would be for me to ask a dummy question and for you to upvote it (giving me 10 point) ... but others would almost certainly immediately downvote it as being silly.

Comment: @mikerodent Please post a good question about webapps I'll upvote it :) PS: if you edit my answer, please add it at the end, and not modify the current working solution :)

Comment: If I could think of one I would! Yes, don't worry I won't mess with your answer.

Comment: The Aug 8, 2021 release of AttachmentExtractor Continued [claims](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor-continued/versions/) to work with Thunderbird 78.0 - 87.0. But I don't know if it works with newer versions.

Comment: One gotcha I encountered when trying this: I went to the settings of AttachmentExtractor and set the default directory to where I wanted the attachments to go. After that, AE delete attachments did not work! Although it gave the warning at the start and the notification after finishing, all attachments remained intact. The solution was to rename the directory before deleting. I am still getting a connection to server timed out error when trying to move the emails back to the gmail folder.

Answer (score 9):

No. 
You can't delete an attachment in Gmail without deleting the email it is attached to. You can forward the message to yourself and manually remove the attachment before hitting send. Then you can delete the original message. Just be sure to use the delete option on that message and not for the entire conversation.

Personally I don't recommend using Gmail as an archive solution. If you are using Google Apps, the enterprise version of Gmail, the message could be expunged by a company policy at any time. If your Gmail account is compromised the messages could be deleted by the attacker.

If the data is important, create a Google Doc and paste the information in it. You can now share this info with others should you wish to share or collaborate on it.

Comment: And what do you base this conclusion on? If you can prove it's wrong, please show your reference(s) and I'll be happy to edit or remove my answer.

Comment: Based on what is posted in the accepted answer (that can be taken as a reference), as one option I am familiar with. That is what I used quite a few years ago.
Perhaps you mean that you can't remove an attachment from a web browser... If so, it would be good to mention it explicitly.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but this is the 'web applications' Stack Exchange and the questions was about GMail. I'm addressing the question in the context it was asked. The accepted answer you reference provides a workaround that involves installing a local (non-web application) email client. So the answer I gave, that you can't accomplish this in Gmail itself, is still accurate.

Comment: Well, this is an "edge" case... Gmail is per-se web based, but there are non-web based interfaces that interact with it, so there is likely no clear-cut classification of the accepted answer as a "workaround".
Indeed, the question (rephrased to make it a question) is "Can I just delete the attachment without losing the email itself?"
It does not ask "Can I just delete the attachment *from within Gmail* without losing the email itself?"

Comment: It's already a question: "Can one delete a _Gmail_ attachment but keep the email?" so to me that means within Gmail. If the question were just about how to delete an attachment from any email, well then I don't think it would be in the Web Applications stackexchange. The nature of the question including the word Gmail and being tagged with Gmail indicates the question is about solutions within Gmail.

Answer (score 9):

The ability to delete the attachment from an email, without deleting the email itself is one of the annoyingly missing Gmail's feature.
You can't do this from the Gmail user interface.
You can achieve this though, by programmatically modifying the emails using [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api).
This is exactly what I did. I created a simple tool that you can use to extract attachments from emails - feel free to check it out:

**[Gmail Attachments Extractor](https://github.com/TeWu/GmailAttachmentsExtractor)**

Comment: Works perfectly! This script helped me process 31,000 emails.

It's a little tedious to set up the authentication in google cloud portal, but that's not the author's fault. The script's output is fantastic, the instructions are complete, and the functionality is great.

The image based auth walkthrough was especially thoughtful given that it's not really the author's problem, but it is the main onboarding challenge for the script.

The author even correctly recommends a security cleanup process of revoking the tokens you grant in order to execute the script. Kudos! Thanks Tomasz!

Comment: Do the copied emails preserve the original attributes such as the original date?

Comment: @dan Yes. It does preserve all the standard attributes (e.g. date, from, to, subject), and extended attributes (e.g. Gmail stars and labels). The only attribute that is changed is the Message-ID, because every email must have a unique Message-ID.

Comment: @TeWu then this is by far the best answer. I'll give it a try. Using a 3rd party such as Firebird is fine although very cumbersome, and the other guy suggesting the app he developped but selling it... it is what it is.

Answer (score 8):

The Chrome extension [Dittach](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dittach/nckdidfgpjgjblkhloeecdmofhgphkmm?hl=en) promises to be able to delete individual attachments.

A short description/review [is available at ZD Net](https://www.zdnet.com/article/dittach-now-lets-you-delete-attachments-in-gmail-without-deleting-the-original-emails/).

Comment: Are the emails processed on Dittach's own servers (i.e. email content + attachment) or is everything done on client side with *no data at all transiting on Dittach's servers*? Also what kind of permission does it require? It's always scary to give permission to our mailbox to a company like Dittach that could potentially be hacked (probably much easier than Gmail themselves...)

Comment: Dittach no longer working as of Jul 2019 - seems like company folded?

Answer (score 2):

Basj's [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125147/300698) here is a good approach. My answer is a modified version, which only works for macOS, because Basj's answer suggested that I might need to install an old version of Thunderbird, which I didn't want to deal with. Instead, I used macOS's Mail program. The difference between Mail and Thunderbird for this use case is that Mail can remove attachments from many emails at once, but Thunderbird needs an extension ([AttachmentExtractor Continued](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor-continued/versions/)) to do it for more than one email at a time, and the extension has historically not always worked with the latest version of Thunderbird. That said, I don't see a way for Mail to *extract* the attachments (rather than just delete them), so if you want the attachments themselves extracted to a local folder then you might need to make Thunderbird work.

1. (Optional) Go to [takeout.google.com](https://takeout.google.com/) and download your Gmail data in case you delete something by mistake. (But it still might not be easy to restore if you delete something by mistake.)
2. Gmail setup (same as Basj mentioned): (a) "Go to Settings, temporarily switch to `Conversation mode off`, `Save settings`" so that you can be sure you're dealing with just the emails for which you want to remove attachments, not other emails in the same conversation threads. (b) "Enable IMAP in Gmail's Settings. Also create a Gmail label named `bigattachments`" and fill it with the emails for which you want to remove attachments.
3. Additional Gmail setup: Create another label `bigattachmentsRemoved`. For now, it is empty.
4. Link Mail to your gmail account. Wait until all the emails in `bigattachments` are synced.
5. On the left panel, hover over "On My Mac" and click `+` to create a new local mailbox named `temp`. This is analogous to creating a local folder in Thunderbird in Basj's answer. It should only exist on your Mac; you shouldn't see it in the Gmail web interface. Select all the emails in `bigattachments` and copy them to `temp`.
6. `View` -> `Show Message Size`. This is important to be able to recognize when attachments have been successfully removed, because Mail can take a long time to do that for many messages, and doesn't show a progress bar!
7. Select all the emails in `temp`, then `Message` -> `Remove Attachments`. This might take a while, and the only indication that it is finished is when the displayed size decreases.
8. Select all the emails in `temp` and copy them to `bigattachmentsRemoved`.
9. Go to Gmail's web interface and wait for the emails in `bigattachmentsRemoved` to sync. Compare them to the emails in `bigattachments`; they should match except that attachments should be missing or replaced with "empty" attachments.
10. Delete all the emails in `bigattachments`.
11. They're still in Gmail's `Trash`. Go there, review the items, then click `Empty Trash Now` to reclaim the storage space.
12. Do any cleanup you like with respect to `temp` and the Gmail labels you created.

For background, the reason why both of versions of this approach (Thunderbird and Mail) involve removing attachments from local copies, deleting the originals, and uploading the modified copies is because Gmail won't let you directly remove an attachment from the original. Gmail will just add a new email and keep the original (with attachment) if you try to do that.